# Receive-Job missing data

Tags: powershell, office365

I have created a PowerShell script to dump some details from Office 365 into a csv. There are 120,000 accounts in the Azure AD. To speed up the process I have split the script up into 25 jobs.

Everything works apart from the output for MFAState and Errors which return no data.

My script previously without using jobs works perfectly. Any ideas why the data is not being returned by the job?

```
#### Editable Section #####
$jobcount = 25                  # Set the maximum jobs
$usersperbatch = 5000           # Users per batch
$username = "user@example.com"  # MSOL Admin account

#### Start Script #####

# Get Credential and connect
$cred = Get-Credential $username

"Connecting to MSOnline"
if (Get-Module MSOnline) {Import-Module MSOnline}

Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred

"Getting MSOL Accounts"
$MSOLUsers = Get-MsolUser -All
"Total Users: $($MSOLUsers.Count)"

# Set counts
$i = 0
$j = $usersperbatch - 1
$batch = 1

while ($i -lt $MSOLUsers.count)
{

    # Pause job creation if jobs equal $jobcount 
    $running = @(Get-Job | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'})
    if ($running.Count -ge $jobcount) {$running | Wait-Job -Any | Out-Null}

    # Create batch of users
    $userbatch = $MSOLUsers[$i..$j]

    # Create Scriptblock for job
    $sb = {
        # Import Arguments
        param ($cred, $MSOLUsers)

        # Connect to AAD
        Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred

        $Results = @()

        Foreach ($m in $MSOLUsers)
        {

            $Result = New-Object PSObject

            $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name DisplayName -Value $m.DisplayName
            $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name FirstName -Value $m.FirstName
            $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name LastName -Value $m.LastName
            $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name UserPrincipalName -Value $m.UserPrincipalName
            $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name WhenCreated -Value $m.WhenCreated   
            $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name GUID -Value $m.GUID
            $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name LastDirSyncTime -Value $m.LastDirSyncTime
            $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name StrongPWord -Value $m.StrongPasswordRequired
            $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name Disabled -Value $m.BlockCredential
            $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name MFAState -Value $m.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State
            $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name IsLicensed -Value $m.IsLicensed
            $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name Valid -Value $m.ValidationStatus
            $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name Errors -Value $m.Errors.ErrorDetail.ObjectErrors.ErrorRecord.ErrorDescription

            $Results += $Result

        } # End Foreach

        $Results

    } # End Scriptblock

    # Create Job Name based on Range
    $jobname = "$i-$j"

    # Start job
    Start-Job -Name $jobname -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $cred, $userbatch

    # update counts
    $batch += 1
    $i = $j + 1
    $j += $usersperbatch

    if ($i -gt $MSOLUsers.count) {$i = $MSOLUsers.count}
    if ($j -gt $MSOLUsers.count) {$j = $MSOLUsers.count}

} # End While

# Get Results
$Results = Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to have `Connect-MsolService` in your `while` loop since you already have it before the loop.

Also I would define the script block before the loop and use another variable name for the user list parameter.

```
#### Editable Section #####
$jobcount = 25                  # Set the maximum jobs
$usersperbatch = 5000           # Users per batch
$username = "user@example.com"  # MSOL Admin account

#### Start Script #####

# Get Credential and connect
$cred = Get-Credential $username

"Connecting to MSOnline"
if (Get-Module MSOnline) {Import-Module MSOnline}

Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred

"Getting MSOL Accounts"
$MSOLUsers = Get-MsolUser -All
"Total Users: $($MSOLUsers.Count)"

# Set counts
$i = 0
$j = $usersperbatch - 1
$batch = 1

# Create Scriptblock for job
$sb = {
    # Import Arguments
    param ($cred, $users)

    # Connect to AAD
    #Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred

    $Results = @()

    Foreach ($m in $users)
    {

        $Result = New-Object PSObject

        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name DisplayName -Value $m.DisplayName
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name FirstName -Value $m.FirstName
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name LastName -Value $m.LastName
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name UserPrincipalName -Value $m.UserPrincipalName
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name WhenCreated -Value $m.WhenCreated   
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name GUID -Value $m.GUID
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name LastDirSyncTime -Value $m.LastDirSyncTime
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name StrongPWord -Value $m.StrongPasswordRequired
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name Disabled -Value $m.BlockCredential
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name MFAState -Value $m.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name IsLicensed -Value $m.IsLicensed
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name Valid -Value $m.ValidationStatus
        $Result | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name Errors -Value $m.Errors.ErrorDetail.ObjectErrors.ErrorRecord.ErrorDescription

        $Results += $Result

    } # End Foreach

    $Results

} # End Scriptblock

while ($i -lt $MSOLUsers.count)
{
    # Pause job creation if jobs equal $jobcount 
    $running = @(Get-Job | Where-Object {$_.State -eq 'Running'})
    if ($running.Count -ge $jobcount) {$running | Wait-Job -Any | Out-Null}

    # Create batch of users
    $userbatch = $MSOLUsers[$i..$j]

    # Create Job Name based on Range
    $jobname = "$i-$j"

    # Start job
    Start-Job -Name $jobname -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $cred, $userbatch

    # update counts
    $batch += 1
    $i = $j + 1
    $j += $usersperbatch

    if ($i -gt $MSOLUsers.count) {$i = $MSOLUsers.count}
    if ($j -gt $MSOLUsers.count) {$j = $MSOLUsers.count}

} # End While

# Get Results
$Results = Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait
```

Comment: Good suggestions. I am getting a single "You must call the Connect-MsolService cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets." by commenting out the Connect-MSOLService in the scriptblock but it still works.

Comment: Unfortunately though it is still not returning anything for MFAState or Errors. Scratching my head.

Comment: It's not normal to have this `Connect-MsolService` prompt, once connected you don't need to reconnect. Also I want to mention I tested the script and it worked for me. Which version of the Azure PowerShell module are you running?